# How to define if this variable is empty in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a variable that is the result of an expression. I want to check if this varaible is empty or not.

Here are two variables:

```
 A=$(cat ${FICHIER_BROKERS} | grep ${DATABASE_NAME} | grep dbo.${TABLE_NAME}\  | awk '{print $4}')
 B=$(cat ${FICHIER_SUBSCRIBERS} | grep ${DATABASE_NAME} | grep dbo_${TABLE_NAME}_CT | awk '{print $4" "$5}' | sed "s/....$//" | sed "s/[-:]/ /g" | awk '{print mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6)}')
```

The result of `A` is empty, because in the awk statement, there is not fourth element (expected).

Now I have this variable that calculates timestamp difference:

```
C=$(expr $A - $B)
```

So far, the variables content are:

```
echo "A $A"
echo "B $B"
echo "C $C"
```

Output:

```
A 
B 1590414895
C
```

I would like to check if C is empty or not. Later on, I need to execute checks (greater than) on it and an empty value returns  `[: : integer expression expected`

To check if the variable is empty, I have tried the following:

---

```
if [[ ! -z $C ]]; then
```

Throws error:

```
expr: syntax error
```

---

```
if [[ "$C" != "" ]]; then
```

Throws error:

```
expr: syntax error
```

---

How can I perform a check on this value ?

Comment: That error comes from the original attempt to define `C`, not your attempt to check if `C` is empty; it means either `A` or `B` is empty.

Comment: @chepner `expr` is not able to "detect" it ? Like assigning a default value to an empty variable ?

Comment: No; parameter expansion happens *before* `expr` runs, so when `A` is empty, `expr $A - $B` is equivalent to `expr - 1590414895`. `expr` has no idea that what the original expression looked like before parameter expansion.

Comment: You could use `C=$(( A - B ))`, which would let the arithmetic expression "expand" `A` and use a default value of `0` instead of an empty string.

Comment: The question is: do you *want* `A` to be 0 if it wasn't set?

Comment: @chepner yes. And the (( A - B )) solution works perfectly well for my scenario;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `expr` itself, because `A` has no value, and the resulting command is `expr - 1590414895`. You are seeing the error *before* trying to check if `C` is empty (which indeed it is, because `expr` never produced any output).

Instead of using `expr` (which is virtually *never* needed), use an arithmetic expression. It will expand string values as if they were parameters, with the side effect of treating null or unset names as having a value of zero.

```
C=$(( A - B ))
```

Comment: beware of Integer Overflow

Comment: Is there any benefit when writing `C=$(( A - B ))` instead of `((C = A - B))`?

Comment: Aside from POSIX compatibility, probably not. If you are using `set -e`, be aware that the exit status of `((C = 0))` is 1, while the exit status of `C=$((0))` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parameter substitution and set a default value `${parameter:-default}`

```
C=$(expr ${A:-0} - ${B:-0})
(( $C )) && echo -e "different"
```

(the other stuff is just playing, basically more posix conform and not related to bash)

because `-z` negated with `!` will extinguish itself you can just skip both test conditions.

for arithmetic tests double parentheses can be used instead of (double) brackets:
`(( $C == 1 ))` is just a test like `[ "$C" = "1" ]` returning *true* or *false*.

as one liner for `if..[]..then..else..fi` conditional evaluation  can be used `[]..&&..||`
`&& <cmd>` is executed when `[]` returned *true*, `|| <cmd>` is executed when `[]` returned *false*

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it